# Can we load XML beans for spring data source according to our CONFIG_MODE in Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

VM argument is : `-DCONFIG_MODE=DEV`

Can I load my respective ${CONFIG_MODE}/spring-config.${CONFIG_MODE}.XML file and get the required beans in spring boot application?

Comment: That is what `@ImportResource` is for. But do you really need an XML for defining the datasource, why not rather use Spring Boot auto config for this?

Answer (score -2):

the springboot project default use @artifactId@-@profiles.active@.yml，so u can follow this rule

```
spring:
  application:
    name: @artifactId@
  profiles:
    active: @profiles.active@
```

if @artifactId@ is testproject and @profiles.active@ is dev
so result testproject-dev.yml

Comment: Don't do this as this requires you to rebuild the artifact for each environment you want to deploy to, effectively leading to an untested artifact in production!.